# SQL Count occurrences in a column and calculate total of another

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum, aggregate-functions, aggregation

I have a derived table that results in this format:

```
    THENAME |    THESTATUS  | THECOST
    ----------------------------------        
      name1 |    statusX    | cost1.1
      name1 |    statusX    | cost1.2
      name2 |    statusZ    | cost2.1
      name2 |    statusZ    | cost2.1
      name3 |    statusY    | cost3.1
                   (...)
      nameN | status(X,Y,Z) | cost
```

each nameN will always have the same status but cost will be different. I am trying to come up with a result that looks something like this

```
Status Groups | Count of Names | Total Cost of Group
       X             2              10
       Y             5              20
       Z             4               5
```

basically, display the total cost of each status and the number of items each status contains.

Going for something like

```
SELECT
     thestatus, 
     COUNT(DISTINCT thestatus),
     SUM(thecost)
FROM THETABLE
GROUP BY thestatus
```

doesn't work and I am thinking if it is even possible to group simultaneously two columns..

EDIT - https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bB1RSy8GV35FGEi3Lr1Tqw/0

EDIT - Not sure if it's the version of MySQL or what, but in the sample data I think it works properly but not in the actual query. It would be impossible to re-create the entire schema and the whole query but perhaps it is something else...

Comment: what is the simple value of `statusX`? the structure of `THESTATUS` string is important to solve your problem.

Comment: statusX, statusY, statusZ would be the simple values if I understand the question correctly. This table derives from a rather complex query with multiple joins, it doesn't actually exists in the database

Comment: You can group by on as many columns as you want. Based on your problem statement, I don't see any issues with your current query. Please edit the question to add some sample data and expected output. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308

Comment: Check: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bB1RSy8GV35FGEi3Lr1Tqw/5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try like below , remove distinct

```
SELECT
     THESTATUS, 
     COUNT(THENAME),
     SUM(THECOST)
FROM THETABLE
GROUP BY thestatus
```

[demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bB1RSy8GV35FGEi3Lr1Tqw/2)

Comment: it actually produces the same result.

Comment: @NikOs how have you checked ? cause distinct name count and cout(name) is not same

Comment: Indeed, in the sample it doesn't produce the same results, it does so in the actual query - not sure how. Nevertheless, it displays the sum of Statuses but I need the number of Names that appear in the results. Please see the fiddle that I created

Comment: @NikOs https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bB1RSy8GV35FGEi3Lr1Tqw/2 does it your expected result

Comment: @NikOs https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bB1RSy8GV35FGEi3Lr1Tqw/4 this is another which one yours expected result?

Comment: Yes!! This is correct! I actually came up with another more complex solution, but this does produce the correct result. Cheers Zaynul Abadin!

Comment: I realise this is the same solution you provided yesterday that it didn't seem to work but I have to say I was frantically trying to come up with the solution and might have missed something..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 

DISTINCT THESTATUS as 'Status groups',

COUNT(THENAME) AS 'Count of Names', 

SUM(THECOST) as 'Total Cost of Group' 

FROM THETABLE GROUP BY THESTATUS
```